# Python change point algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, matplotlib

I am experimenting with a change point algorithm from the ruptures package. I dont see anything in the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/ruptures/) but I am curious to know if a time delta can be calculated between the change points???

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ruptures as rpt

#read CSV file

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Building-Demand-Electrical-Load-Profiles/master/School%202013_2014%20KW.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
df2 = df.loc['2-11-2014']

points2=np.array(df2.kW)

#Changepoint detection with the Binary Segmentation search method
model = "l2"  
algo = rpt.Binseg(model=model).fit(points2)
my_bkps = algo.predict(n_bkps=3)
# show results
rpt.show.display(points2, my_bkps, figsize=(17, 6))
plt.title('Change Point Detection: Binary Segmentation Search Method')
plt.show()
```

For example if I run the code above it will output the matplotlib below. Can a time delta in hours be retrieved between change points?? The dataset is a building electrical demand time series data.

[image]

***EDIT***
I got a little help from the author of ruptures... Here's the code

```
kWmean = df.mean()

#Changepoint detection with the Binary Segmentation search method
model = "l2"  
algo = rpt.Binseg(model=model).fit(points2)
my_bkps = algo.predict(n_bkps=3)
# show results
rpt.show.display(points2, my_bkps, figsize=(17, 6))

# getting the timestamps of the change points
bkps_timestamps = df2.iloc[[0] + my_bkps[:-1] +[-1]].index

# computing the durations between change points
durations = (bkps_timestamps[1:] - bkps_timestamps[:-1])
#ours
d = durations.seconds/60/60
d_f = pd.DataFrame(d)

oneHr = d_f.values[0][0]
twoHr = d_f.values[1][0]
threeHr = d_f.values[2][0]
fourHr = d_f.values[3][0]

one = f'first change point {oneHr} hours'
two = f'second change point {twoHr} hours'
three = f'third change point {threeHr} hours'
four = f'fourth change point {fourHr} hours'

plt.title('Change Point Detection: Binary Segmentation Search Method')
plt.text(0, kWmean+15, one)
plt.text(0, kWmean+10, two)
plt.text(0, kWmean+5, three)
plt.text(0, kWmean, four)
plt.show()
```

[image]